# Find out which IAM account manually triggered a scheduled function

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP Cloud function which runs on a schedule every morning. The logs show that it has been triggered off-schedule three other times in the last week, which I presume can only happen if someone has gone to the Cloud Scheduler page and clicked 'Run now' on that function. How can I find out who did this? The Logs Explorer doesn't show this information. (Heads will not roll, but IAM permissions may be stripped. Bonus points if it turns out to have been me.)

For scheduled functions, there are two sets of logs - one for the cloud function triggered by the schedule, and one for the Cloud Scheduler itself. In the logs for the Cloud Scheduler, only the daily schedule shows up, not the extra triggers.

Log of the function starting in the logs explorer for the Cloud Function:

```
{
  "textPayload": "Function execution started",
  "insertId": "REDACTED",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "region": "REDACTED",
      "function_name": "REDACTED",
      "project_id": "REDACTED"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-05-04T08:49:37.980952884Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "REDACTED"
  },
  "logName": "projects/REDACTED/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/REDACTED/traces/REDACTED",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-05-04T08:49:37.981500851Z"
}
```

Comment: what's the trigger for the function ? is it http call ?

Comment: Post one of the Cloud Scheduler logs redacted as JSON text (not an image). Most services record identity information. I am not sure if Cloud Scheduler does. https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/viewing-logs

Comment: @GaurangShah, it's a scheduled function.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks, I've edited my post above

Comment: Do you have [Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/audit-logs?hl=en) enabled for Cloud Functions?

Comment: @ser - is there any other log entries (maybe the one before this log entry) that indicate what started the Cloud Scheduler task?

Comment: @JohnHanley absolutely nothing, sadly! I've looked at: all the logs for the specific Cloud Function for the hour preceding the function starting, the logs for the scheduler for the preceding 1 hr, and the whole Logs Explorer with no filters at all for the preceding 1000 ms.

Comment: @Andrés We don't have them enabled - I've just discussed it with my boss, who says that those logs only reveal things like changing admin permissions, not who ran a function.

Comment: What type of authorization do you have enabled for the Function?

Comment: @ser what's the trigger for the function. if it's let's say http and without authorization I don't think you can figure out who called it.

Comment: It is possible there were not enough available instances when it was scheduled, and then the Cloud Function ran later by a retry. What are your min_instances settings for this Cloud Function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the trigger of your Cloud Function is `http` and without authorization, it will be very hard (or near impossible) to figure out who called it.

Additionally, it is possible there were not enough available instances when it was scheduled, and then the Cloud Function ran later by a retry.